# What are fitness sharing and niche count in evolutionary computation?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, terminology, genetic-algorithm, definition, evolutionary-algorithm

What are "fitness sharing" and "niche count" in the context of evolutionary computation?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Evolutionary algorithms (EAs) tend to converge to a single solution as the diversity of the population diminishes [[1]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.48.9077&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This behavior is known as *genetic drift*. Any technique that maintains diversity in the population based on the distance between the population members is called a *Niching technique*.

Fitness sharing is a type of Niching, where the fitness of each individual is scaled based on its proximity to others. This means that good solutions in densely populated regions are given a lower fitness value than comparably good solutions in sparsely populated regions. In effect, the algorithm's selection technique places less emphasis on these high-quality, high-density solutions.  The distance can be calculated based on the values in either decision space (genotype), solution space (phenotype), or both (as in Goldberg and Richardsen [[2]](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=MYJ_AAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA41&dq=genetic%20algorithm%20with%20sharing%20for%20multimodal%20function%20optimization&ots=XvsLvo7yDE&sig=QBQDidpJkhe9vL_IVNFF2JEgnEk)). Distance in genotype is usually defined using the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) whereas distance in phenotype is usually defined using [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

A simple fitness sharing method is given by the following Java method:

```java
    /** 
    * Computes the shared fitness value for a solution
    * @param index the index of the solution for which a shared fitness value will be computed
    * @param minDist any solution closer than minDist will share fitness with the current solution
    * @param shareParam a parameter that defines how much influence sharing has. Higher = more sharing.
    * @param population the array of solutions. Each solution has a genotype and associated fitness value.
    */
    public double computeSharedFitnessValue(int index, double minDist, double shareParam, Solution[] population){
      
      double denominator = 1;
      
      for(int j = 0; j < population.length; j++){
      
         final double dist = hamming_dist(population[index],population[j]);
      
         if (dist < minDist){
            denominator += (1-(dist/shareParam))
         }
      }
      
      return population[index].getFitnessValue()/denominator;
    }
```

**Motivational Example:** The following figure perfectly illustrates why fitness sharing is so important in multi-objective problems. In Figure A (left), diversity was maintained throughout execution. As a result, the solutions span a considerable portion of the true Pareto front (shown here as wire frame). In Figure B (right), the population only converged to a small area of the Pareto front. In many situations, even if the solutions in Figure B were of higher quality, a decision maker would prefer the diversity of options provided in Figure A to the (nominal) improvement in quality of Figure B.

[image: Pareto Diversity]

**Additional Resources:**

- [[1] Genetic algorithms with sharing for multimodal function optimization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.48.9077&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [[2] Genetic Algorithms for Multi-Objective Optimization: Formulation Discussion and Generalization](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=MYJ_AAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA41&dq=genetic%20algorithm%20with%20sharing%20for%20multimodal%20function%20optimization&ots=XvsLvo7yDE&sig=QBQDidpJkhe9vL_IVNFF2JEgnEk)

Comment: Great answer.  Could you expand on the difference between explicit and implicit fitness sharing?

Comment: @user3144201 Implicit fitness sharing differs from the explicit form in that no explicit distance metric is required.